# how does the hidden field keep its value on post back

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

Does any body have any idea how does the hidden field keep its value on post back when it is value is set from javascript and not from the server side code?

Can I create a text box that has this feature?

Comment: Do you mean "keep it's value AFTER post back"? Then, this would be a server-side feature. Otherwise, this questions does not make sense to me, see the answer of @Ben.

Answer (score 1):

I worry I'm not understanding your question...  but <input type="hidden" /> name/values get passed with a form like any other input, and you can certainly set their values with JavaScript, if you want.  when you submit the form, it doesn't care - or even know - how the input fields got their values.